# binary search tree bst

Tags: java, binary-search-tree

So, I need to build an unbalanced binary search tree, create a method to balance it, which i did by building a sorted array based off a level order traversal ( or at least attempted to ), then print out the balanced binary search tree. Here is my attempt, but it is only outputting memory locations. HELP !

```
    public class BalanceTree {
      public static BST balanceTree(int[]list){
       if(list.length==0)//if length is zero, then empty list, cannot balance
         return null;

       return balanceTree(list,0,list.length-1);}//recursively call balance 

     public static BST balanceTree(int[] list, int begin, int end){//take sorted array from unbalanced tree
       if (begin>end) 
         return null;
       int mid = (begin+end)/2;//find midpoint, assign as root node
       BST chld = new BST(list[mid]);
       chld.left = balanceTree(list,begin,mid-1);//assign as left child
       chld.right = balanceTree(list, mid+1,end);//assign as right child
       return chld;
     }


    public static void levelOrderPrint(Node node){
            int h = height(node);
            for(int i=1; i<=h;i++){
               printLevel(node,i); //print every level

            }
    }
     public static int height (Node t)//find height of tree
      {
        if (t.left == null && t.right == null) //leaf check
          return 0;
        else if (t.left == null)
          return 1 + height(t.right);
        else if (t.right == null)
          return 1 + height(t.left);
        else
          return 1 + Math.max(height(t.left),height(t.right));
      }

     public static void printLevel(Node node, int level){
            if(node ==null){
                return;
            }
            if(level == 1){
                System.out.println(node);
            }
            else if (level > 1){
                printLevel(node.left,level-1);
                printLevel(node.right,level-1);
            }
        }


     public static void main(String[] args) { 
      Node node = new Node(); 
      node.root=26; 
      int [] sortedArray = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26};


      System.out.println("Now Building Unbalanced Tree. Root Node: " + node.root); 
      node.insertNode(node, 25); 
      node.insertNode(node, 24);  
      node.insertNode(node, 23);  
      node.insertNode(node, 22);  
      node.insertNode(node, 21);  
      node.insertNode(node, 20);  
      node.insertNode(node, 19);  
      node.insertNode(node, 18);  
      node.insertNode(node, 17);  
      node.insertNode(node, 16);  
      node.insertNode(node, 15);  
      node.insertNode(node, 14);  
      node.insertNode(node, 13);  
      node.insertNode(node, 12);  
      node.insertNode(node, 11);  
      node.insertNode(node, 10);  
      node.insertNode(node, 9); 
      node.insertNode(node, 8);  
      node.insertNode(node, 7);  
      node.insertNode(node, 6);  
      node.insertNode(node, 5);  
      node.insertNode(node, 4);  
      node.insertNode(node, 3);  
      node.insertNode(node, 2);  
      node.insertNode(node, 1); 
      System.out.println("*********************************************");
      System.out.println("Now building balanced binary search tree: ");

      //int[] arr = 
      levelOrderPrint(node);// I know this should be the array " arr" which is passed into the balance tree method
    balanceTree(sortedArray,0,25);// I know this must use the array from the "levelorderPrint" method,
    //but i could not get it to compile, so i substituted in an already sorted array.



     } 
     }

      public class BST{//constructing bst node
       int val;
       BST left;
       BST right;
       BST(int x){
         val = x;}
     }
    public class Node {
 Node node;
 int root; 
 Node left; 
 Node right; 

 public void insertNode(Node node, int num) { //building unbalanced tree
  if(num < node.root) // if current node is less than root node, insert to the left
  { 
   while(node.left != null) 
   { 
    node = node.left; 
    if( num > node.root){ //if current node is greater than root node, insert to the right

     Node temp = new Node(); 
     temp.root = num; 
     node.right = temp; 
     System.out.println("Inserting "+ num + "" + "at right of" + node.root); 
    } 
   }
   Node temp = new Node(); 
   temp.root = num; 
   node.left = temp; 
   System.out.println("Inserting " +num + "" + "at left of" + node.root); 
  } 
 }

 public String toString(){

   return root+ "";

 }


}
```

Comment: *"HELP !"*  Ask a question!  (And stop SHOUTING at us.)

Comment: I apologize ! shouldn't my levelOrderPrint method be printing out the tree instead of the node memory locations ? I am new to Java, i apologize in advance. any help or input is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Every Object in Java implements the toString() method. By default (as written in the Object class) the object will print its "memory location".

To be able to print an Object in Java you will need to overwrite the method toString().

Comment: I am just confused because I thought thats what my levelOrderPrint() method was doing .

Comment: In your printLevel method you're calling:
System.out.println(node);

This means you will print Node.toString(). You need to reimplement this method inside Node to show what you want.

Answer (score 0):

In your line `System.out.println(node);` you tell Java to call `node.toString()`.  Because you didn't make your own `toString()` method for the custom `Node` class, Java automatically uses the `Object.toString()` method, which returns the memory address.  Consider adding something like the following to your code:

```
public class Node {
    ...
    public String toString() {
        return root + "";
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: I made a toString() method in my Node class but now the output for the balanced tree is just printing 26 down to 2 in descending order.

Comment: Well the order of the output is another matter altogether.  Experiment with the order of the 3 statements: `print(currentNode)`, `print(leftNode)`, `print(rightNode)`.
Consider http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal.

Comment: I want to print the tree using a level order traversal, in my print level method, im printing the root, then left node, right node, then dropping down to the next level. Is that wrong ?